# Slight error in calculations

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to build a game somewhat like Wheel of Fortune, actually it's done but there seems to a weird issue I can't figure out.

Here's the wheel itself, as you can see the values are spaced evenly, each having a 15 ° slice.

[image]

To spin the wheel I generate a random number which will be the amount of rotation in degrees, I animate the wheel and everything is fine but when the rotation stops I have to get the value from the wheel which stops at the top-center position so I though this would solve it:

```
wheelValues = [
    1000, 3250, 1800, 1000, 1200, 3750, 5000, 1000, 3000, 1600, 1000, 3500,
    1000, 2000, 1000, 2750, 1000, 4000,   -1, 1000, 2500, 1400, 1000, 2250
];

if (toAngle > 360)
{
    toAngle = toAngle - (Math.floor(toAngle / 360) * 360);
}
arrIndex = Math.floor(toAngle / 15) + 1;
result = wheelValues[arrIndex];
```

where `toAngle` is the random spin I generate which can be between 370 and 1440.

This method works in about 8/9 times out of 10 and I can actually get the correct value the wheel stops at but I can't really understand why sometimes the value is off (and sometimes really off, not even near the correct value).

Comment: Neither can we without some kind of reproducing demo, I'd think.

Comment: It's a mobile app, I don't know how I could show you how it works.

Comment: toAngle can be simplified using the modulus operator. toAngle % 360

Comment: I think you want an even multiple of 360, so `toAngle -= toAngle % 360`, but if you do that it will end on the same value every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I can see;

Firstly, this line:

```
 if (toAngle > 360)
```

If toAngle == 360, I believe this will produce an error, as you will skip the 'modulus' section and toAngle will finally be 24 (larger than your dataset)

Second:

```
arrIndex = Math.floor(toAngle / 15) + 1;
```

No need to +1 this, as you will never get your first value, and on occasion you will exceed the array bounds.

Also, as to why you get odd values, have you tried to write some simple code to debug your assumptions? Write a loop, that iterates from 370 to 1440 (your stated input boundaries) and see what your calculation comes up with for each value. Print it to a file, or screen and you can quickly scan to see where the issues might be.

Answer (score 3):

You're adding 1 to your array index for some reason.

array indexes start from 0.

Comment: Yeah, I know. In an older version I had `Math.floor((toAngle - 7.5) / 15) + 1` and needed the +1 there. Anyway, this still does not explain why I sometimes get values so far from the correct one.

Comment: Like, what for instance? What do you get in toAngle which gives you a wrong result? Please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, it's probably best if you make your random number an even multiple of 15 degrees in the first place, then you don't need all that rounding and flooring, e.g.

```
function randDeg() {
  var epoch = 360; // minimum value
  var max = 1440;  // maximum value to return
  var step = 15;   // even multiple to return
  var t = Math.random() * (max - epoch) | 0;
  t -= t % 15;
  return  t + epoch;
}
```

Will return a number n where epoch <= n <= max and n%15 = 0.

Comment: well, this is definitely a great idea, I'll give this a try.